# How to list pools in linux redhat?

Tags: linux, redhat, solaris

In Solaris, using zpool list command to list available pools.
What is the command for listing pools in Linux red-hat 7.6

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LVM-based storage pools, you can use something like `virsh pool-list --all`
There's extensive documentation at docs.redhat.com.
There's also ZFS on RedHat, but you have to install it separately.

Comment: Then, how to install ZFS, kindly let me know